# Trouble Scraping Contents of a <span> Using Simple_HTML_Dom

Tags: php

I'm trying to scrape prices from homedepot.com and amazon.com. Home Depot is working great, but I am having trouble accessing the Amazon price with the scraper.

For reference, the way I am getting the Home Depot price is like this:

```
$element = $dom->find('span#ajaxPrice.pReg',0);
```

The way I am trying to get the Amazon price is like this:

```
$element = $dom->find('span#priceblock_ourprice.a-size-medium.a-color-price.priceBlockBuyingPriceString',0);
```

I am getting error: Trying to get property 'innertext' of non-object for my Amazon URLS. The main difference I see is that homedepot.com has a `content = "23.99"`, while amazon has it directly inside the `<span>`

Here is the full function for reference:

```
function checkPrice($url)
{
    global $SKUS;
    global $amazonURLS;
    global $urls;
    $price = 0;

    if(strpos($url, 'homedepot.com') !== false)  
    {  
    $dom = file_get_html($url, false);
    $element = $dom->find('span#ajaxPrice.pReg',0);
        if(!isset($element))
        {
            $price = 0;
            return $price;
        }
        if(isset($element)) 
        {
            $price = $element->content; 
            $price = strtok($price, "$");  //idk the best way to do this in PHP so lets do this
            $priceFloat = floatval($price); 
        }
    }
    else if(strpos($url, 'amazon.com') !== false)  
    {
        $dom = file_get_html($url, false);
        $element = $dom->find('span#priceblock_ourprice',0);
        if(null === $element->innertext)
        {
            echo "FAILED";
            $price = 0;
            return false;
        }
        if(null !== $element-innertext)
        { 
            $price = $element->innertext; 
            $price = strtok($price, "$");  
            $priceFloat = floatval($price); 
        }
    }
    return $priceFloat;
}
```

I am getting the echo "FAILED" above for each amazon price read attempt and echoing $element returns completely empty value.

Comment: Did you try `$dom->getElementById("priceblock_ourprice");` ?

Comment: @Jamie_D Just tried it, but unfortunately, still no luck.

Comment: Tried every combination I could think of, like span#priceblock_ourprice.a-size-medium, the full line, etc.. Still nothing, any ideas? It gets the line when I check with document.querySelector(), but it's grabbing empty content, a "non-object".

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that Amazon may have some kind of anti-scraping security measures in place. See [this article](https://blog.datahut.co/challenges-that-make-amazon-data-scraping-so-painful/) . Check the content of the $dom object returned from the `file_get_html` call and see if actually a real page.

Comment: Do a `var_dump($dom); exit();` right after your `$dom = file_get_html($url, false);` line.

Comment: It prints out the whole doc as an array of searching the doc basically (massive). I did document.querySelector('span#priceblock_ourprice')
and it pulls it up on chrome developer tools. So, basically the scraper is not finding that area, and it's returning null.

Comment: In the dump it actually doesn't even look like it's getting any HTML. I think they are blocking scrapers. I tried changing my user agent but no luck. Only trying to scrape 4 URLS for testing